# operative priority with multiple signs

Tags: signal-processing

hi everyone I'm confused with the following problem.

-+-(-5)

how I can resolve this?.
first change the value inside of parenthesis or I begin from left to right?.

Comment: These are all unary operators, so work from the right to the left. And yes, do the operation inside the parenthesis first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as saying $-1 * 1 * -1 * -5$, so order does not matter (commutative property of multiplication). The answer would be -5.